# Sharepoint generating hundred of webservice calls before "'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page" dialog shows

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, web-services

When a user does an operation on a publishing page that would take them away
from the current page, we get the warning dialog about moving away. The thing
is that it takes for ever to show up, 20-30 seconds.

Using fiddler I found out that the page is making several hundred requests
against the PublishingService.asmx. Each time calling the Wait method with a
value of 100 milliseconds.

Is this normal ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post for a solution
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/09/16/avoiding-those-ldquoare-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away.aspx